# Run Tampermonkey script on domain but not on iframes

Tags: iframe, youtube, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How can I prevent Tampermonkey from running on iframes?

E.g. I write a script for

```
// @include       http://*.youtube.com/*
// @include       https://*.youtube.com/*
```

The script will also run on external websites with embedded YouTube players. That's unneeded and even expensive when Tampermonkey fires 20 times on a page with 20 YT players.

How can I set the script to only fire when the surfed website is youtube.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script really only runs at Tampermonkey (and/or Greasemonkey and/or Scriptish) you also can use the [`@noframes` directive](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#@noframes).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that option (but should have). Poorly written doc page anyway ;)